# How do I select all code inbetween comments with Notepad++ (regex)

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I'm trying to select a block of code between 2 comment tags like this:

```
<!-- begin answers -->
   ...[code]
<!-- end answers -->
```

I've tried something along the lines of `<!-- begin answers -->.*<!-- end answers -->` but my regex knowledge is fairly limited. My knowledge of Notepad++'s find and replace is very limited as well, but the reason I'm using it is because of the "Replace Across Open Files" option deems to be very useful. Reason for this because I'm doing a search/replace on about 4000 files.

The code between these comments may vary somewhat (spaces, whitespace) so I need something a little flexible to handle it.

Thanks!

Comment: With Notepad? bwahahaha. I don't think Notepad knows what a regular expression is. Heck, if *Outlook* can't do regular expressions, then asking poor little Notepad to do it is asking a lot.

Comment: @Ether: Notepad++ (note the two plus signs) is a product vastly superior to the lowly Windows Notepad. Check it out: http://notepad-plus-plus.org You might really like it.

Comment: I'm open to any other shareware that can do find/replace like I need above across multiple files/directories.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Paul: I am hereby humbled. :)

Comment: [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com) is a good shareware editor with decent regex support, and it can also search and replace across multiple files. You get the best regex support in [EditPadPro](http://www.editpadpro.com), but unfortunately it doesn't have a Replace in Files function. [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) (by the same author) does (but isn't an editor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression you tried should work but unfortunately, the regex engine that Notepad++ uses (Scintilla) cannot match across new lines.  So there is no way of doing it. 
This limitation is documented [here](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html).  Also it only supports very basic expressions.  And you cannot select just the text between the comments (without selecting the comments too) because look-ahead and look-behind assertions are not supported.

Comment: To quote the documentation YWE mentions: "Note that `\r` and `\n` are never matched because in Scintilla, regular expression searches are made line per line (stripped of end-of-line chars)."

Comment: As an aside, Notepad++'s regex does support find/replace with groups, so it *is* possible to do a find and replace that only selects text between matches (.e.g. Replace "(START\s*)(.*)(END)" with "\1Replacement\2") would replace "START EVIL END" with "START ReplacementEND".  But yes, Notepad++'s find/replace is pretty lame.  And if you give it even a moderately sized file with massive quantities of find/replace, find and replace chokes badly.

Comment: How about using an Extended search to replace newlines with a magic sequence (e.g. ##), then perform your Regular Expression replacement, then restore newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You could use since Notepad++ v~ 6.0+:

search what: `(?<=<!-- begin answers -->\r?\n).*?(?=<!-- end answers -->)`

This will highlight all code that is between `<!-- begin answers -->\r?\n` and `<!-- end answers -->`

Be sure you have tick `Regular Expression` and `dot match newline`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small application to read the file as a long string.
Then determine the index of the first comment using something like...

```
xml.IndexOfAny("<!-- begin answers -->".ToCharArray(), 0, xml.Count());
xml.IndexOfAny("<!-- end answers -->".ToCharArray(), 0, xml.Count());
```

Once you know the indexes, you can use SubString to find what's between. You will have to play around with the indexing of the start and end to find exactly what's between. The above code is in C# but there is equivalent API in Java.

Answer (score 0):

[YWE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081442/how-do-i-select-all-code-inbetween-comments-with-notepad-regex/4081850#4081850) is exactly right about why your regex isn't functioning properly; +1 to him.

See code below to get an idea of how easy it is to do something like this in Python. Please note that this operates on one file, but you can easily modify to search and replace a directory of files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

def main():
    FIN = 'fin.html'
    FOU = 'fou.html'
    with open(FIN, 'r') as fin, open(FOU, 'w') as fou:
        re_sub = re.compile('<!-- begin answers -->(.*)<!-- end answers -->', 
                            re.DOTALL) # DOTALL enables multiline patterns
        text_to_search_replace = infile.read()
        outfile.write(re_sub.sub('...[some new code]', text_to_search_replace))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) documentation
[Python regex HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.2/howto/regex.html) by A.M. Kuchling

Answer (score 0):

Using the below in Find & Replace (***Regular expression*** and ***.matches newline*** selected) works for me:

```
<!-- begin answers -->(.*?)<!-- end answers -->
```